# Notifications on a youtube playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube

i've been struggling with this subject for ages, since there does not seem to be a concrete answer.

I'm creating a playlist of youtube videos and i would like to get notification when you press fastforward and so.The problem is my youtube video is being played by a htmlsting, which does not use a MPMoviePlayerController property. Therefor i cant use NSNotifications, which i need.

a lot of people telling me to use LBMoviePlayer or other sample codes there are extracting the youtube video. The problem is that, this is illegal and probably wont make the app through the review.

My question is then. Can it really be true that there are no way to play a youtube video and get notifications when any of the buttons pressed, without using an extractor?

my code atm:

```
    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'%0.0f', height:'%0.0f', videoId:'%@', events: {  } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";


        embedHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat: youTubeVideoHTML,
                     webView.frame.size.width,
                     webView.frame.size.height,
                     [[array valueForKey:@"link"] objectAtIndex:0 ]];

[webView loadHTMLString: embedHtml baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://youtube.com"]];
```